# Why isn’t “the passengers were perished” correct?

Tags: passive-voice, exam-questions, active-voice

> The plane was crashed and the passengers _________

**perished** (OR) **were perished**

The given answer is **perished**.

According to my understanding, Since **and** is a conjunction, it connects passive voice with passive voice. The part of the sentence before **and** is in passive voice. So is the part after **and** should also be in passive voice?

Comment: Aside: there is another usage of *perished*. "We were perished" means "We were very cold." See [Lexico³](https://www.lexico.com/definition/perish).

Comment: ...and another transitive use is "the rubber seal was perished (rotten)."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to interpret a text fragment that probably wasn't even written by a native speaker

Comment: It could be the question is too basic, but in some languages the translation of *passenger perished* would be *passengers are perished*. (Italian is one of those languages.) I can understand why a user could be confused by how to correctly use the past tense in English, even though the comment by @charmer about *"were" vs "are"* also applies to Italian.

Comment: @ColleenV I would like to bet a small sum of money that the question was taken from an English grammar exercise book and the OP **copied the text incorrectly**. It wouldn't be the first time, it certainly won't be the last. I am always going on about sources, and if the OP has correctly copied the text. However, if the aim of the exercise is to identify any errors in the text/sentences this would explain the anomaly. But if the exercise had "The plane was crashed" then it is rubbish and the OP is well advised to throw the entire book away.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree. There are far too many sub-standard texts out there purporting to teach English. Sometimes though having someone correct a mistake is a better lesson than being told the information.

Comment: @ColleenV A cursory look at the OP's profile page tells me  that they never respond to comments nor any (if any) requests for clarification, which is a shame and puzzling at the same time.

Comment: @charmer `The use of 'were' implies that they are not perished anymore. i.e. they've risen from the dead`  Would "The spies were killed" mean that the spies are no longer dead? What about "The house was destroyed in the storm." does that imply the house was rebuilt? No.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I view people who are willing to engage with native speakers of a language that they’re still learning as terribly brave. If they have an answer that satisfies them, I’m not too surprised that they might not want to discuss it further.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, I'd agree with you there. But if you're brave enough to post a question, which can be nerve wracking, why not post a clarification in a comment. Or better still,  edit the question! Zero edits by the OP.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Passive voice can only be used with *transitive* verbs.  That is, verbs with both a subject and an object.  In the passive voice, the original subject is removed and the object becomes the new subject.

For example:

> She ate **the apple**. ("the apple" is the object that "she" ate)
>
> **The apple** was eaten. ("the apple" is the subject that someone ate)

The verb "to perish" is not a transitive verb in American English, and in British English the transitive usage applied to a person means "to be made very cold", so you can't put "to perish" meaning "to die" into the passive voice.  That is, in the sentence below:

> The passengers perished. (no object that the passengers act on)

there is no object to be "promoted" to subject in the passive voice. Writing "The passengers **were perished**," would mean, "someone perished the passengers," which is a nonsensical use of the verb **perish**.

Even your first clause, "The plane was crashed," is strange.  If the active form is "**The plane crashed**," then there is no passive equivalent because **crashed** is an intransitive verb and there is no object in this clause.

It is possible to use "to crash" as a transitive verb, but this is rare and surprising for a plane and we'd usually have some extra word(s) to express how strange this was.

For example:

> The pilot **deliberately** crashed the plane. (here, "the plane" is the object)
>
> The plane was **deliberately** crashed.

Again, the plane is moved from object to subject, and we have the word **deliberately** to emphasize that this is the unusual transitive meaning rather than the much more typical intransitive meaning.

It is grammatically acceptable to mix transitive and intransitive in the same sentence:

> The plane **was loaded** with cargo and **took off** shortly thereafter.

Here we have the passive "was loaded" followed by the active phrasal verb "took off."

Comment: When I hear "the plane was crashed" the first thing I think of is [that time when NASA deliberately sent a Boeing 720 into the desert.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Impact_Demonstration) There were no passengers in that case, and not even any pilots—the pilots were in the aircraft for takeoff and then parachuted out, and it was flown to the crash site by remote control.

Comment: And yet "the rubber hose was perished" or "my hands were perished" are perfectly valid, so it's a bit more subtle than a blanket 'grammatically impossible'.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I don't think your two examples sound grammatical.  In fact, I'm not even sure what those sentences are _trying_ to convey.

Comment: @KirkWoll Say I have an old car and the brakes failed because the rubber hose were perished. How would you describe the hose's state in the past within your idea of English grammar?

Comment: @PeteKirkham I would say, "the brakes failed because the rubber hose had perished."

Comment: @KirkWoll that's also valid, but seems wrong to me (UK) just like if writing a report I'd say 'were broken' rather than 'had broken' (reflecting that they were in that state when I found them). 'had' also doesn't work for perishing from cold  as 'had perished' means died whereas 'were perished' means very cold.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I wonder if this is one of those British vs American English differences? I mean, I'd agree with Kirk that "was perished", "were perished", etc. sound flat-out ungrammatical, and I notice that both of us list our location as California.

Comment: David Z could be correct. I'm in the eastern US, but I would never use "perish" in the sense of cold or rotten. It sounds obsolescent to me.  I would use "perishable", but for perishable materials which were, indeed, perished, I would say they are old, or past their due date, etc.

Comment: @PeteKirkham 'were broken' makes sense because 'broken' is also an adjective. 'Perished' is only a verb. Part of the issue is definitely US vs UK, though - merriam-webster.com gives two definitions of "perish" that it notes as "chiefly British", and one of them is a transitive verb.

Comment: [MW says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perish) that this verb can be transitive (British) also [perish the thought](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perish-the-thought).

Comment: Does adding already as a comparison between different pasts make "were perished" correct? As in "the passengers were already perished" implying "by the time the rescue team arrived"

Comment: @FluidCode The passengers _had_ already perished. Consider the verb die vs. the noun dead. The passengers _had_ already died. The passengers _were_ already dead.

Comment: My first language (a long time ago) was British English.  As well as the verb to perish, perished could be an adjective meaning what happens to rubber when it shrivels up after a long time and (jokingly?) to mean very cold or thirsty (perhaps analogous to the rubber drying out meaning.)  I should add that I mostly recall it being used in that way  by my mom who learned her English in Tyneside in the 1920s.  So in the plane crash example, the passengers were perished would mean they had shrivelled up or were very  cold.  To say they had been killed would be, "The passengers perished."

Comment: @PeteKirkham This transitive usage is not idiomatic in AmE.  Question - would you find it idiomatic in BrE when applied the actual death of a living person, or just applied to wear-and-tear?

Comment: @CanadianYankee for a person, 'they were perished' would mean they were very cold, for something made of rubber or leather that it had degraded and wasn't soft and supple any more, but prone to cracking or crumbly. For food it would mean 'gone off'. So not quite wear and tear either.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - Okay, I've modified the entry to reflect that "to perish" meaning "to die" is never transitive.

Comment: "The plane was crashed" sounds fine if it was done deliberately.  "The passengers were perished" does sound a bit odd, but if the plane was deliberately crashed, then "were perished" continues the sense of deliberate action carrying across.  Granted, it doesn't sound like standard English; nevertheless it has a bit of a poetic sound to it.

Answer (score 9):

The coordinating conjunction *and* doesn't have to carry over the passivity. Note that if it did coordinate passivity, you wouldn't repeat *were* anyway.

But what it depends on is the actual verb used. *perish* is intransitive, so it has no passive.

> They will perish. They perished.

Actually, the use of the transitive/passive *was crashed* is odd here too. It suggests that someone chose to crash the plane. "The plane crashed" is expected.

Answer (score 2):

All of these are grammtically correct:

> The plane was crashed and the passengers were perished

- For some reason the pilot deliberately crashed the plane. (Maybe controlled crash landing if it was on fire or something?)
- All of the passengers were very cold (e.g. they landed on a mountain
  in winter)

> The plane crashed and the passengers were perished.

- The plane crashed for some unknown reason
- The passengers were very cold

> The plane was crashed and the passengers perished.

- The plane was crashed deliberately for some reason
- The passengers died

> The plane crashed and the passengers perished.

- The plane crashed for some unknown reason
- The passengers died

---

How *likely* they are to be "the correct answer" depends on:

1. the context of the rest of the piece
2. the tone of voice of the rest of the piece
3. what the examiner had in their head when they wrote the test question.

For example, I note that [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/perish#perish__2) lists "were perished" as a primarily British usage, so you'd be less likely to find it in an American context. (It also sounds a little old fashioned to me, but that's a judgement call)

If all you're being asked about is grammar, either option is fine. If you're being asked for a stylistic choice or to fulfil a given meaning then one or the other may be "correct".

Comment: As a native American English speaker, the meaning of "were perished" ("were very cold"?) you used is unintelligible to me. I would have had no idea it could mean that, and would have had to look it up trying to figure out what it meant.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE, yeah I tried to touch on that at the end of my answer that it's probably more common over this way — within the UK, maybe even particularly in northern England I think, but would be also be perfectly understandable in Ireland. You could say "were perished with cold/hunger" — using "were perished" on its own feels like it has an unsaid, implied reason on the end (normally cold).

Answer (score 2):

"Perish" is an *intranstive* verb.  It does not take an object.  To use passive voice, you need a *transitive* verb.  Therefore you cannot say "the passengers were perished".

However you can say, "The apples were perished."  The reason is that "perished" is used like an *adjective* in that sentence.

You can also say, "The passengers perished."  The reason is that "perished" is used in active voice in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving parallelism (that is, making the second part of the sentence passive voice because the first part is) has a low priority. Preserving parallelism is more of a stylistic issue, and grammatical rules take precedence. (And if we did have parallelism, it would allow us to omit the verb anyway, for instance in "The plane was sinking and the passengers drowning." there's an elliptical "were" before "drowning".)

As Canadian Yankee says, "perish" being an intransitive verb creates problems for the passive voice. In the passive voice construction "[noun] was [verbed]", the noun is what would be the object if the verb were in active voice. So that does imply the verb should be transitive. However, I don't think it's entirely correctly to say the passive voice requires a transitive verb; the noun can be an indirect object: "The store was gone to" is a bit awkward, but not grammatically incorrect. The real issue is that "passengers" simply is not the object, indirect or otherwise, of "perish". Putting in a transitive verb does not fix this issue, if passengers remain the subject of the verb. For instance, "The passengers gave up hope" can't be made into "The passengers were given up".

There's also the issue of whether "was crashed" actually is passive voice. It could be analyzed as simply past tense with "crashed" being an adjective rather than past participle. This would still be awkward wording, but it would eliminate the issue of preserving passive voice parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer (I trust it's simple) is that plane crashed (an event), and that the passengers perished (an event - death).  If the passeners "were perished" (from the obscure Collins usage aboue), it would imply a *process* (ongoing), not an *event* (even though it would be in the past tense.)

For example, if the quote was "the passengers were perishing", it would have implied a process, that they were dying (not necessarily at the same time).

But since "perished" is firmly in the past tense, the sentence means they're already dead.

"The plane crashed and the prisoners perished."  is the correct answer.  If you said "were perished" (an very unusual usage), it would strongly imply an outside agency, e.g. someone killed the passengers (not the crash itself - that was an event prior to any scenario involving "were perished".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all answers and maybe I add nothing new but it is a correct use of language. It means that the passengers felt cold. That's surely the case after they perished!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you may be trying to say is "The plane had crashed and the passengers had perished". That is it occurred in the past from the time of the events you are narrating.  E.G. "The search teams climbed the mountain and found the plane had crashed and the passengers had perished".