# What is the grammatical error in "Apart from Federer, I have not seen a stronger player"?

Tags: grammaticality

> Apart from Federer, I have not seen a stronger player.

The sentence is grammatically incorrect. Why is it incorrect?

Comment: if' you're removing Federer from the comparison... who are you comparing?  i'd be more tempted to say Apart from Federer, i have not seen a strong player.  since you remove comparisons with the first phrase.

Comment: @neuralstatic: I agree with the potential problem that you point out (depending on context/intended meaning), but I don't think that your suggested wording works, because that version would say that all other players are *not strong*, not merely that they're *not as strong as Federer*. Rather, if the goal is to say "I have not seen any player stronger than Federer", then the way to say that is . . . wait for it . . . "I have not seen any player stronger than Federer".

Comment: It's grammatically incorrect because it states that Federer and the narrator haven't seen a stronger player than some third unnamed person. And that's not the intended meaning.

Comment: @PatrickT, except that is not what it says. "Apart from Federer" clearly does not modify  the narrator (*"I"*), and *"seen"* is not applicable to Federer. It simply doesn't fit to misconstrue it as Federer and the narrator having seen.

Comment: "The sentence is grammatically incorrect..." - source?

Comment: @neuralstatic correct, or you can say „(Apart from Federer,)I have not seen any strong player, apart from Federer“

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect — just lacking context.

Comment: Obviously they have just been talking about some other player X. And therefore the sentence means "...a stronger player than X." So some of these comments are irrelevant. (And the sentence looks perfectly grammatical to me.)

Comment: @BruceWayne - *Grammarly*... probably... ;-)

Comment: Who told you that this sentence was incorrect & what was their rationale?

Comment: It's _possible_ that a mediocre grammar check utility is flagging this sentence because the name ends in *-er*, and using an adjective there instead of a noun would be incorrect.  I think most of them are better than that these days, though, especially with the capital letter there.

Comment: Are you trying to say that Federer is the strongest player you have ever seen? Or that another player that you have been discussing is the second strongest player you've ever  seen (with the strongest being Federer)?

Comment: @Kevin ...or that being apart from Federer has not resulted in you seeing a stronger player (stronger than who, we don't know).

Comment: @DoctorDestructo I don't know of any sane person who would parse the sentence that way

Comment: @Kevin Neither do I, but I believe that is the only interpretation that would make it grammatically correct.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo It is just fine the way it is.

Comment: Bobson: Like “Apart from lighter, titanium is also stronger than steel”, and your grammar checker says it’s should be “apart from being lighter…” :-(

Comment: @Kevin It's fine if the speaker is trying to say that being apart from Federer has not resulted in them seeing a stronger player. If they're trying to say something else, then they're using incorrect grammar.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Only if you are being extremely pedantic and prescriptivist

Comment: @Kevin True, and in the real world, people pick the most rational interpretation, not the most grammatically correct. Still, I probably wouldn't use this sentence if I was trying to teach someone correct English.

Comment: I have already mentioned this before, [**sources need to be cited**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292484/smitha-sat-close-quite-beside-her#comment546405_292484). Furthermore, the OP [does not respond to comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292328/why-isn-t-the-passengers-were-perished-correct#comment546404_292328) nor simple requests for clarifications. Sadly it's -1 from me.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo you are wrong.  The interpretation of "second strongest player" is also entirely grammatically correct (and I believe how most people would interpret it).  "Apart from" can and often is used as a synonym for "aside from", so this sentence can be read as saying "Aside from Federer (that is, excluding Federer from any implied comparison), I have not seen a stronger player (than the person we're talking about)" and it is an entirely correct sentence if that was what was meant.

Comment: @Foogod If I'm wrong, it has nothing to do with my definition of "apart from". I believe that the text before the comma should relate to the subject immediately after it, not the object at the end of the sentence. Otherwise, we might interpret "After dinner, I ran into another old friend" as referring to a friend called "dinner".

Comment: @Foogod Of course, I realize that people will naturally favor whatever interpretation makes the most sense in context (which may or may not be the interpretation you describe). Fortunately, our ability to understand each other doesn't depend on strict adherence to grammar rules.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo ah, I see, you are favoring the "misplaced modifier" theory.  As I commented on Jeffrey's answer below, this is not an example of a misplaced modifier.  It is actually an example of [fronting](https://www.thoughtco.com/fronting-in-grammar-1690875), which is entirely grammatically acceptable.  This is clearly the case because "apart from" (when interpreted as meaning "excluding") is *not a noun modifier* at all, but actually an adverbial phrase, so the fact that it ends up in front of a different noun is irrelevant to the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Foogod I see 3 possibilities: a) the speaker means "I have not seen a stronger player, except for Federer", in which case there is a misplaced modifier; b) the speaker means "I have not seen a stronger player than Federer", in which case there is **also** a misuse of the phrase "apart from"; and c) the speaker means "I have not seen a stronger player while I have been apart from Federer", in which case there is no error. I don't see any "fronting" (a.k.a. Yoda speak) in this sentence. None of the examples in the page you linked are structured anything like it.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo in your (a) case, you seem to be mistakenly thinking that "except for Federer" is modifying "player".  It is not.  It is modifying "have not seen" (it is equivalent to saying "have not seen *except in the case of* Federer").  As I already said, it is actually an *adverb*, not an *adjective*, and as an *adverb* its position relative to nouns is irrelevant, and it is therefore *not* a misplaced modifier in that case.  (comments are not really for discussion, though, and this has already gotten too long, so that's all I'm going to say on the subject..)

Comment: @Foogod If "apart from Federer" is an adverb, then it describes how the speaker performs the action (of not seeing a stronger player). That is an argument in favor of my original (admittedly facetious) interpretation-- which does, indeed, have no misplaced modifier. Substituting "except for" doesn't change the rules in this case, it just makes the sentence incomprehensible.

Comment: @Foogod Using the definition of "apart from" that you suggested, we get "Except in the case of Federer, I have not seen a stronger player". The only way this does not have a misplaced modifier is if you interpret it as "I have not seen a stronger player while I have been except in the case of Federer". _You can't solve this problem by using an alternate definition of "apart from"._

Answer (score 30):

I don't think there's an error in that sentence. It's acceptable to start a sentence with a prepositional phrase, including ones like "except for" and "apart from".

[Here](https://www.opentextbooks.org.hk/ditatopic/4537) is a page with a more thorough explanation of prepositional phrases, and when and where they can be moved.

Comment: It's spoken English, and implies a conversation between two people who are discussing some player we do not see. The prepositional phrase is fine.

Comment: This was my gut instinct, spent way too long trying to find something wrong with the sentence before I scrolled down.

Answer (score 30):

This sentence says clearly and grammatically correctly that you have just been watching the second strongest or possibly strongest player you’ve ever seen, and that you have also seen Federer, who is the only player you have seen who may have been stronger.

Comment: It just depends if the OP is actually in that context.  If they're in a context where they're just trying to say Federer is the best then I'd say this sentence is awkward at best.

Comment: The most grammatically correct interpretation (I believe) is "I have not seen a stronger player while [I have been] apart from Federer"-- in which case we can't even assume that Federer is a player.

Comment: That seems to me to be the most natural interpretation too. I find it hard to see what the other answers are driving at.

Comment: Quite obvious that “apart” means “with the exception of”, and not “while separated from”.

Comment: This answer is the best as it takes into account pragmatics. Two people are talking about some player that is NOT Federer. Apart from Federer, I have never seen [as I am seeing right now or have just seen] a better player.

Comment: @gnasher729 Without context, I don't think the meaning is quite obvious. But my comment was really more about what the word was referring to than its definition.

Answer (score 25):

This is what traditionalists call a [**misplaced modifier**](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-misplaced-modifiers.html). I use the word "technically" below to indicate the traditional perspective, the one we can read about in textbooks written for young people.

When a modifying phrase is next to a noun phrase, it technically modifies *that* noun phrase.

In this case **Apart from Federer** is a modifying phrase. It is next to **I**, so technically it modifies **I**. It therefore seems to indicate that **I** is **apart from Federer**, and this is clearly not the author's intent. The author wants to describe the object of the comparison.

If someone has called the sentence "incorrect," they are probably thinking of this traditional rule.

In practice, "misplaced modifiers" rarely cause genuine confusion. Native speakers "misplace" modifiers all the time, and their audience usually understands the intent. The meaning of the Federer sentence is perfectly clear.

That said, the careless placement of modifiers can cause miscommunication, often with comic results. Consider the following:

> Crying and screaming throughout the funeral, the dead man was mourned by his friends and family.

A dead man was **crying and screaming**? Your audience will no doubt get the point, but some of them may be inclined to laugh at an inappropriate moment.

Comment: What would be the "correct" form of the sentence then?

Comment: Just move the "Apart from" to the other end of the sentence, putting it in proximity with the part you want to modify: "I have not seen a stronger player apart from Federer". (Though I would use "than" instead of "apart from").

Comment: I don't think the mistake you're describing happens here, that's how "apart from" works basically all the time. If you have an indefinite subject and definite object or vice versa, it's obvious that "apart from" applies to the one that's indefinite. See "*Apart from your dad, everyone is here*" and "*Apart from your dad, I've greeted everyone*". Here's it's clear "apart from" applies to "everyone", no matter what's next to it.

Comment: @chepner That or "*I have not seen, apart from Federer, a stronger player*".  But I disagree with your suggestion of "*I have not seen a stronger player than Federer*", which changes the meaning of the sentence entirely.  That makes the sentence *only* about Federer, and completely omits the original intent of being about another (unnamed) player who's almost as strong.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't follow. The implicit assumption in either is that you are comparing any other player you have seen to Federer.

Comment: I don't think the original necessarily has to involve a 3rd player. That's a separate assumption altogether.

Comment: The classic example, possibly by Jim Brewer, is: “Outside of a dog, a book is Man’s best friend. Inside a dog, it’s too dark to read.”

Comment: @chepner The original sentence is clearly talking about a player that the speaker is observing, saying that they are the strongest player they have ever seen, with the exception of Federer.  The phrase "apart from" is used explicitly as a comparison, similar to "except for" or "other than", etc.  It makes no sense to use such a phrase unless there is an implied comparison.

Comment: As I wrote, this is a *technical* error, not necessarily a genuine error. You have to work pretty hard to write this sort of sentence in a way that the audience cannot understand.

Comment: When you say that the modifying phrase is “next to I, so technically it modifies I” you are quoting a prescriptive out-dated rule that is so often broken in ordinary (even formal) usage that it simply doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Orbital Aussie, Your complaint is *exactly* what the word "technically" indicates. I am attempting to explain to OP why someone—who is not me—called the sentence incorrect.

Comment: @Davislor  The confusion illustrated by your example doesn't occur because of a misplaced modifier.  Rather, it occurs because "outside" switches meanings:  In the first sentence it's used as a classifier, while in the the second it's used to indicate physical location.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney, I'm going to agree with Orbital Aussie that "technically" is a poor description of the difficulty here, but for somewhat different reasons. Outside of the use of "technically", your answer is very much what I would write, should I answer the question. Based on Walden University's online style guide (https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/modifiers), this is not a "rule" per se, but rather a construction that could be ambiguous or misunderstood (perhaps easily so). To be continued . . .

Comment: @JeffreyCarney, part 2: Your link, and a_shovel's, and mine, all validate that placing the modifier *near* its object is desirable, but none indicate it is a *rule*. *Technically* seems to indicate, to me, that someone regards this as a *rule*.  I would describe it as a potential source of confusion. And, I would further describe the OP's assertion of incorrectness as itself incorrect, as it isn't a rule, but a style preference for clarity of communication.

Comment: Yep, this is nicely demonstrated in this obligatory reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4vf8N6GpdM (Grammar Nazi by College Humor)

Comment: Also, "Everyone is here, apart from Dad" does not mean that "here" is "apart from Dad". "Everyone, apart from Dad, is here" sounds strange.

Comment: @user253751 But in that example, it's clear how to attach the modifier, because "apart from Dad" clearly attaches to some NP referring to people.

Comment: With some modifiers, "misplacing" it in this way seems far more common than not. For example, the construction "I shop only at 7-Eleven" is very rarely used, as far as I can tell; almost invariably "I only shop at 7-Eleven" is used instead, even though the speaker seems clearly not trying to indicate that they do nothing other than shopping.

Comment: Perhaps address the [prepositional phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294080/what-is-the-grammatical-error-in-apart-from-federer-i-have-not-seen-a-stronger/294107#294107) argument in your answer (but ***without*** meta talk about another answer). And ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: No one seems to understand this: Spoken English and written English are not the same thing.

Comment: @theorist In Davislor's Jim Breuer example, it is "outside" in the physical sense in *both* sentences. It's just that we are fooled into thinking it is metaphorical in the first sentence, until the second sentence coerces a revised, "physical" interpretation on the first -- I think that's the better analysis. So the first sentence's construction is indeed ambiguous, but any reasonable person will effortlessly choose the metaphorical interpretation. So it actually serves to explain why the grammar scold did not have a particularly good point (as to which this answerer would probably agree).

Comment: @Lambie Even in the most formal written context, almost no one would consider that sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: I would actually argue that in this case, this is *not* a misplaced modifier.  It is actually an example of [fronting](https://www.thoughtco.com/fronting-in-grammar-1690875), and as such actually *is* grammatically correct.

Comment: I've always understood the term _grammatically correct_ to mean "follows the formal rules identified by academics who study and teach grammar", whereas some of the comments here and elsewhere seem to indicate that it means "easily understood" or "commonly used by the general public". If there was a convenient way to identify which definition we're currently using, we could avoid a lot of arguments. My preference would be to force those other definitions to find a different label.

Answer (score 3):

While I like Jeffrey Carney's answer (and upvoted it), I will write my own because I believe one thing about the question should be made clear. While the questioner's sentence may seem confusing or ambiguous to some, it is *not* grammatically incorrect. It would be clearly understood by native speakers under most circumstances.

However, as a matter of style, this sentence may not constructed in the clearest way. What you see in the sentence is possibly a *misplaced modifier*[1]. Supposedly, one could understand the phrase *"Apart from Federer"* to refer to the speaker (*"I"*), but in this sentence I think such a misunderstanding would be highly unlikely. One can find examples of far more egregiously misunderstandable sentences at the sources linked in the footnotes. Additional sources to understand misplaced modifiers are at [yourdictionary (dot) com][2], and [opentextbooks (dot) org][3].

The Walden Univ source describes *misplaced modifiers* as

> When a modifier is ambiguously or illogically modifying a word, we consider it a misplaced modifier.

And, the *yourdictionary* description:

> It’s important for modifiers to stick close to the word or words they’re modifying. When they stray too far, they become misplaced modifiers — and if they get too far, it may look like they’re modifying something else.

You will notice that none of the resources linked puts modifier placement in the "rules to obey" column, as we have with some other grammatical instances. ***What is important in each description is that the modifier be placed for clarity of understanding***. A pedant might take issue with the placement of *"Apart from Federer"*, because it is not directly adjacent to *"a stronger player"*. However, since, in this usage the *"apart from"* phrase clearly modifies *"a stronger player"*, it would not be misplaced. If one were concerned for absolute clarity, with no chance for misinterpretation, then perhaps:

> I have not seen a stronger player, apart from Federer.

or

> I have not seen, apart from Federer, a stronger player.

However, personally I find both cases to be more uncomfortable and lacking the immediacy and dynamic exclamatory style of the original. As I said above, one can easily find examples of truly misplaced modifiers, whose placement would lead to gross misunderstanding or confusion. But I don't think this is one.

```
  [1]: https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/modifiers
  [2]: https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-misplaced-modifiers.html
  [3]: https://www.opentextbooks.org.hk/ditatopic/4537
```

Comment: It, for "Apart from Federer" to modify "I", would not make sense

Comment: (the incorrect grammar in the previous comment is deliberate)

Comment: As the ex-Mrs Federer said: “Apart from Federer, I have never visited a tennis court again”.

Comment: @gnasher729, a humorous counterpoint! But your modification changes the sense, and those changes alter the circumstances and the answer. Your construction ***is*** ambiguous, and I still maintain the original construction is not. Even if you simply added the *"ex-Mrs"* bit to the original, it still only makes sense the one way, and might only barely be misconstrued. It is easy enough to find other instances of truly misplaced modifiers. The modifier does not ***have*** to be directly adjacent, if the intended meaning is clear.

Answer (score 3):

> The sentence is grammatically incorrect.

I don't think this statement is true.

The sentence *may* (or may not) be *semantically* incorrect *based solely on the context*.

In case it is not preceded (expectably immediately) by a reference to another player (that is, the *better* part is a comparison to Federer himself), then it **absolutely is**.

Otherwise it is perfectly legal and comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

In this very example it is perfectly clear what the speaker wants to communicate. But let's exchange **I** for **we**.

> Apart from Federer, we have not seen a stronger player.

Now it is not perfectly clear anymore: have we not seen any stronger player, except for Federer, or has none of us, except for Federer, ever seen any stronger player.

I think this is the reason why those types of constructions are not seen as 100% correct.